# WebKitGTK is slow or sometimes hangs completely in kde plasma

Tags: plasma, webkit

Using Epiphany browser, as a similar display Safari, to check if the site is displayed correctly (I am a web developer), very uncomfortable, scrolling with the mouse, poking something, all as if in 15fps, when as in firefox, chromium, everything flies. Also when I made a game on tauri (like electron, but uses the system webview, in the case of Linux - webkitgtk), and everything is the same, and if a long time open window, it could hang at all.

At the same time, the same Epiphany, but on a laptop, works well, smoothly. The difference between laptop and PC is that on the laptop Gnome 43, and on the PC KDE Plasma 5.27, and I certainly do not know much about the depths of de, but I have a theory that the problem is that KDE Plasma uses Qt, and WebKitGTK, on GTK and some simple programs, such as GParted what, the compatibility layer chews well, but large as WebKitGTK with a creak.

Does everyone have the same problem with kde plasma and maybe there is a solution?

<sub>I don't speak good English. The message has been translated through a translator.</sub>